# Lua - initializing

Tags: c++, lua

I can't init lua correctly under Arch Linux. Lua - latest version. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"
{
    #include <lua.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
    #include <lualib.h>
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *luaVM = luaL_newstate();
    if (luaVM == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error initializing lua!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    luaL_openlibs(luaVM);
    lua_close(luaVM);

    return 0;
}
```

> /tmp/cc0iJ6lW.o: In function `main':
>   test_lua.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to`luaL_newstate'
>
> test_lua.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs'
>
> test_lua.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `lua_close' collect2: ld
>
> returned 1 exit status

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you link with `-llua` and `-llualib`?

Comment: Forgot :( Thank you. What to do when there isn't answers in the topic but the question is solved?

Comment: I guess either wait if KennyTM puts it in an answer or put it in a (community wiki?) answer yourself.

Comment: Semi OT: This is not a problem of "initing", it's a problem of linking. Initing is what happens once you start the program (after it has been linked successfully).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link with the Lua library by passing the `-llua` and `-llualib` flags.

Comment: There's no -llualib in Lua 5.1.