# problems embedding lua in c++

Tags: c++, c, lua

I am attempting to embed lua code in C++, and I'm getting a strange compiler error.  Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
}

int main() {
    lua_State *luaVM = luaL_newstate();
    if (luaVM == NULL) {
        printf("Error initializing lua!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    luaL_openlibs(luaVM);

    luaL_dofile(luaVM, "test.lua");

    lua_close(luaVM);

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++ -Wall -o embed -llua embed.cpp
```

and the error is:

```
g++ -Wall -o embed -llua embed.cpp
/tmp/ccMGuzal.o: In function `main':
embed.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `luaL_loadfilex'
embed.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not calling `luaL_loadfilex` or `lua_pcallk` from my code, which lends itself to the assumption that the problem is not in my code, but in lua itself.  does anyone have any ideas here?

**UPDATE**

Here is my version info:

```
$ lua -v
Lua 5.2.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2011 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Comment: See also: [embedding lua code in c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11728128)

Comment: @MartinSchröder note that that also was my question.  I decided that, having figured out what was causing that problem (lualib doesnt exist), it was better to ask this as a new question that keep editing that one.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the problem was that the libraries are named differently by version.  When installed from the repository, the libraries are called `liblua5.x` and `liblualib5.x`, and therefore the following command was required:

```
g++ -Wall -o embed embed.cpp -llua5.2 -llualib5.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Pre 5.1 answer: According to [this website](http://csl.sublevel3.org/lua/), you need to add `-llualib` after `-llua` if you include `lauxlib.h` and `lualib.h`:

```
g++ -Wall -o embed embed.cpp -llua -llualib
```

#### Update

Silly me, you should always link files/libs in the order they use the other. If `A` uses `B`, you should mention A before B.

In your case, since `embed.cpp` uses `lua`, then you should write:

```
g++ -Wall -o embed embed.cpp -llua
```

Comment: according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441513/lua-initializing), there is no `lualib` in lua >5.1.  when I add `-llualib`, i get a new error, backing this up:  `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llualib`

Comment: @ewok, what is your lua version?

Comment: @Shabaz, I have moved the links, but to no avail.

Comment: @ewok, do you get the exact same error?! Try `nm` on the lib file of lua and check if those symbols exist in it.

Comment: @ewok, did you `nm` on lua's lib file?

Comment: If you are in linux, find where you have installed/compiled lua, there should be a file named `liblua.a` or something like that. In that directory, run `nm liblua.a`, it will list all the symbols existing in that file. If it's not there, we have to find which library has defined them. If they are there, we have to figure out why `g++` doesn't find them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14705/discussion-between-shahbaz-and-ewok)

Comment: Did you install lua from somewhere or did you build from the source?

Answer (score 2):

In in lua 5.2.1  `luaL_dofile` is a macro that is declared like so:

```
#define luaL_dofile(L, fn) \
    (luaL_loadfile(L, fn) || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
```

in your version of lua it might very well be implemented with `luaL_loadfilex` and `lua_pcallk`, and you get undefined references like @Shahbaz said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
cc embed.cpp -o embed -llua -L../lua -I../lua -lm -ldl
```